# Difference between Microsoft Monitoring Agent (MMA) and OMS Agent

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

There are two types of monitoring agents used for Azure virtual machine: **Microsoft Monitoring Agent (MMA)** and **Operation Management Suite (OMS)**. These can be used to connect to Azure Log Analytics workspace and sound interchangeably. What are main differences between MMA agent and OMS agent?

Comment: Deprecation note: Both MMA and OMS are being [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/azure-monitor-agent-migration) in favor of Azure Monitor Agent (AMA). The Log Analytics agent will be retired on August 31, 2024.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Microsoft Monitoring Agent** is a service **just** used to watch and report on application and system health on a Windows computer, it collects and reports a variety of data including performance metrics, event logs and trace information.

To the **OMS**, it is not just for **Log Analytics**, it has several [service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/operations-management-suite/operations-management-suite-overview#oms-services), like  Log Analytics, Automation, Backup, Site Recovery, Log Analytics is one of them.

Comment: If I only need monitoring, would MMA be enough?

Comment: @ThuanNg Yes, it is enough.

Comment: Also Microsoft Monitoring Agent runs it's own copy of window defender under certain circumstances. Bit me recently

Comment: OMS stands for Linux VMs. https://github.com/microsoft/OMS-Agent-for-Linux